# creating thumbnail image from videos saved in parse

Tags: ios, iphone

hi i have gone to parse and read the documentation about objects and file, query as well i have gone through the net and tried to look for way to retrieve the .mov file from parse and use this method:

```
- (UIImage *)loadImage:(NSString *)videoPath
{
    // getting the frame of the video for the thumbnail
    //NSString *videoPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:image ofType:nil];

    NSURL *vidURL = [NSURL URLWithString:videoPath];
    AVURLAsset *asset = [[AVURLAsset alloc ] initWithURL:vidURL options:nil];
    AVAssetImageGenerator *generate = [[AVAssetImageGenerator alloc] initWithAsset:asset];
    NSError *err = NULL;
    CMTime time = CMTimeMake(0, MPMovieTimeOptionNearestKeyFrame);
    CGImageRef thumbImg = [generate copyCGImageAtTime:time actualTime:NULL error:&err];


    return [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:thumbImg];
}
```

to be able to use the file for a thumbnail image now i really need some help here seriously i have been trying everything i can think of im begging please help me i have gone to parse.com forums and no one has answered my questions about how, i have gone to treehouse forums and no answers at all its like no one knows or no one wants to answer the question for me please help.

its been about two weeks since i got stuck on this issue

if i have not asked the question correctly of clearly please let me know so i will edit the question

Answer (score 0):

URLWithString: takes a string representation of a URL. videoPath returns a path, not a URL, that is why you have to use:

```
NSURL *vidURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:videoPath];
```

Hope this help

Comment: i changed the NSString parameter to NSURL and this is what i place in cellForRowAtIndexPath                                            PFFile *thumbnail = [object objectForKey:@"VidFIle"];             NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:thumbnail.url];     self.thumbnailImageV = (PFImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
    self.thumbnailImageV.image = [self loadImage:url];